# Temporary View in Spark Structure Streaming

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

In ForeachBatch Function Structured Straming I want to create Temporary View of the Dataframe Received in the Micro Batch

```
func(tabdf, epoch_id):
    tabaDf.createOrReplaceView("taba")
```

But I am getting below error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Table or view not found: taba
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'taba' not found
```

Please anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: try to use 'createOrReplaceTempView' function

Comment: I have used the same But It's not working. Not getting the View created in current spark session

Answer (score 10):

A streaming query uses its own SparkSession which is cloned from the SparkSession that starts the query. And the `DataFrame` provided by `foreachBatch` is created from the streaming query's SparkSession. Hence you cannot access temp views using the original SparkSession.

One workaround is using `createGlobalTempView/createOrReplaceGlobalTempView` to create a global temp view. Please note that global temp views are tied to a system preserved database `global_temp`, and you need to use the qualified name to refer a global temp, such as `SELECT * FROM global_temp.view1`.