# Autoloader - creating tmp view

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, databricks-autoloader

Im using autoloader to incrementally load the data into silver layer from bronze tables where I use changeFeed feature.

This is how I read the `df`

```
df = spark.readStream.format("delta") \
.option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
.table("mdp_prd.bronze.nrq_customerassetproperty_autoloader_nodups")
```

I also use the `def` to pass this function inside `ForEachBatch` when writing the stream.

part of function look like this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
def update_changefeed(df, epochId):
    filtered_df = df.filter(col("_change_type").isin("insert", "update_postimage", "delete"))
    filtered_df.createOrReplaceTempView("test2")
```

Running the writing part of the code failes:

```
df.writeStream.foreachBatch(update_changefeed) \
 .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_directory) \
 .trigger(availableNow=True).start().awaitTermination()
```

error telling me that `The table or view "test2" cannot be found`.

I tried to test the function and create the `tmp view` out of the streaming `df` and it worked. I think the problem is when the function is passed to `ForEachBatch` it does not create it there. Is there any fix or solution to this?

Comment: what are you doing inside the foreachBatch? Are you doing merge?

Comment: Yes, indeed. But the probelm was to create the `global` view rather than a "simple" view. I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709024/temporary-view-in-spark-structure-streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @Greencolor. As you said we need to use global view.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def update_changefeed(df,id):
    ndf1 = df.filter(col("fare_amount")>10)
    ndf2 = df.filter(col("fare_amount")<10)
    ndf1.createGlobalTempView("test1")
    ndf2.createGlobalTempView("test2")
    spark.sql("show  views  from global_temp").show()
```

output for above function.

[image]

results.

[image]

This is because from documentation,
**TEMPORARY** views are visible only to the session that created them and are dropped when the session ends.
As mentioned in the follow up solution thread, that is the dataframe created from the session cloned from original. So, it is valid to that specific session.

You see below it printing view with dataframe session and not for original spark.

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def update_changefeed(df,id):
    ndf1 = df.filter(col("fare_amount")>10)
    ndf1.createOrReplaceTempView("test1")
    temp_views = df.sparkSession.catalog.listTables()
    print(f"Views in this batch:{temp_views}")
    spark.sql("show  views  from  default").show()
```

[image]

Comment: when will the `global` view be dropped ? I dont want it to be saved after spark session ends

Comment: when your current session ends or cluster restarted.

Comment: You can use `createOrReplaceTempView` inside but while querying use spark session through dataframe like this `df.sparkSession.sql("select * from test2").show()` inside function.